# Is it possible to use Amazon Glacier as backup target for CloneZilla?

Tags: backup, cloud, clonezilla

If I boot up a system with the CloneZilla LiveCD, is it possible to create a image of an entire disk and upload it to Amazon Glacier?

**Edit:**
Maybe my question could be misunderstood. I know that it is possible to create images of entire disks with CloneZilla. The question is, if CloneZilla is also able to store the generated disk image on Amazon Glacier, without the need to have a device/disk space for storing the temporary disk image on it.